# How to change password in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, change-password

How to change the password in Ubuntu 16 using command?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Use command "passwd"

shrikant@shrikant-B250M-DS3H:~$ passwd

Changing password for shrikant.

(current) UNIX password:

Enter new UNIX password:

Retype new UNIX password:

passwd: password updated successfully